# Vertx event bus not communicating in single JVM

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-eventbus

I have two verticles as below

First verticle is just listening on a address **test** and reply to messages

```
public class FirstVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

@Override
public void start()  {
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(FirstVerticle.class);
 vertx.eventBus().consumer("test",message->{
            logger.info("message received " + message.headers());
            message.reply("hi!!!!");
        });
}
}
```

Second verticle just sends a message to address **test**

```
public class SecondVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
        public void start() throws Exception {
            Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SecondVerticle.class);
           
            vertx.eventBus().request("test","hey there",handler->{
                if(handler.failed())
                    logger.error("Failed to get data"+handler.cause());
                else
                    logger.info("response " + handler.result().headers());
            });
    
    
        }
    }
```

The two vertciles are deployed using a common main class

```
Vertx.clusteredVertx(new VertxOptions().setHAEnabled(true), vertx ->
                vertx.result().deployVerticle(verticleName, new DeploymentOptions().setHa(true))
        );
```

When running as a separate program and deploy the verticles in different JVM, verticles can communicate with each other using event bus, but when deploying two verticles using common class at a time is not working, getting below error

```
 Failed to get data(TIMEOUT,-1) Timed out after waiting 30000(ms) for a reply. address:
 __vertx.reply.9da86cc6-f689-47d5-a5b4-bceafbce254a, repliedAddress: test
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the complete program?

Answer (score 0):

Vertx event bus can communicate within a JVM.

It was my mistake that I configured the event bus interceptor, but did not completed the chain by calling context.next().